# Foreach loop until i == x

Tags: c#, asp.net, while-loop, foreach

I want to run a foreach loop as soon as i > x
I have tried i while loop before foreach
Do loop
But the foreach still runs even if i has been equal
I can't figure out how I should run it

I need it to run 9999 times, then do some stuff, and then start over with the next 9999 and so on

I have updated with the whole code
I need to go true all rows in the datatable with batchsize 9999 at the time and then go run restsharp and then go to next 9999

When all the rows in the datatable is done i need to go up to sql query and run the next query, and then new datatable and the same batchsize 9999

Please help

This is my code

```
        protected void run_Click1(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var body = "";
            string[] evenNums = new string[3];
            evenNums[0] = "2";
            evenNums[1] = "3";
            evenNums[2] = "4";
            var daytime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"));
            var day = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SE"));
            foreach (string Site in evenNums)
            {
                body = "{\"requestId\": \"144x25\",\"items\": [";


                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
                {
                    string conn_str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection1"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conn_str);

                    string query = "SELECT [number],[surname],[forename],[emailAddress],[taxIdentifier] FROM[Customer]  WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE[CustomerID] IN(SELECT[CustomerID] FROM[Visit] WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE[GamingDate] Between convert(Date, DATEADD(DAY, -365, GETDATE())) AND convert(Date, getdate())) AND(EmailAddress IS NOT NULL) AND(ContactTypes & 1 = 1) AND(HomePropertyID = " + Site + ") /*  2= Malmö  3=Göteborg  4=Stockholm  */ AND(LEN(TaxIdentifier) = '12')";

                    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

                    conn.Open();
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

                    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(comm))
                    {
                        adapter.Fill(dt1);
                    }

                    string newFileName = "C:\\temp\\" + ort + "" + day + "FromNeon_Cleaned.csv";
                    string clientHeader = "number" + "," + "\"surname\"" + "," + "\"forename\"" + "," + "\"repsonseId\"" + "," + "\"responseTime\"" + Environment.NewLine;
                    File.WriteAllText(newFileName, clientHeader);


                    int batchSize = 2;
                    bool willBreak = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            DataRow dtRow = dt1.Rows[j];

                            if (i == j)
                            {
                                break; // in there what you want as I understand
                               willBreak = true;
                            }

                            var number = dtRow.ItemArray[0];
                            var surname = dtRow.ItemArray[1];
                            var forename = dtRow.ItemArray[2];
                            var emailAddress = dtRow.ItemArray[3];
                            string taxidentifier = (string)dtRow.ItemArray[4];
                            //string taxidentifier = "2211221143";

                            if (Personnummer.Valid(taxidentifier))
                            {

                                body += "{\"itemId\": \"" + number + "\",\"subjectId\": \"" + taxidentifier + "\"},";

                            }

                            body = body.Remove(body.Length - 1);
                            body += "]}";
                        }
                        if (willBreak) break;
                    }



                    var url = "https://marketing.spelpaus.se/api/marketing-subjectid/mw41yZpBFC";
                    var client = new RestClient(url);
                    var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.Post);
                    request.AddHeader("authorization", "vGrpkoNEWHpMuQVrIKVGfsfx2l7SLbsSfQ7PbISjMyiK545ezHW5BzsfPgJq0HA6");
                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                    //var bodyy = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
                    request.AddBody(body, "application/json");
                    RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)

                    {
                        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content);

                        var alloweditemsdata = (obj.allowedItemIds);
                        var responseId = (obj.responseId);

                        //var responseId1= Convert.ToInt32(responseId.value);
                        dt1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt1.Columns["number"] };


                        foreach (int alloweditem in alloweditemsdata)
                        {
                            DataRow Drw = dt1.Rows.Find(alloweditem);

                            var numberresult = Drw.ItemArray[0];
                            var surnameresult = Drw.ItemArray[1];
                            var forenameresult = Drw.ItemArray[2];
                            var emailAddressresult = Drw.ItemArray[3];
                            string taxidentifierresult = (string)Drw.ItemArray[4];


                            string clientDetails = " " + numberresult + ",\"" + surnameresult + "\",\"" + forenameresult + "\",\"" + emailAddressresult + "\",\"" + responseId + "\",\"" + daytime + "\"" + Environment.NewLine;

                            File.AppendAllText(newFileName, clientDetails, Encoding.Unicode);

                        }

                    }

                
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Read the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements

Comment: If you don't want to run code when i==j, then use `if (i != j) { code goes here }`, instead of breaking when i==j. (Also, `var evenNums = new string[3] { "2", "4", "6" };` would save a few lines.)

Comment: Is `HomePropertyID` in the database a string or a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 nested for-loops, the outer with loop variable `i` and the inner with loop variable `j`. But you nowhere actually **use `i`**, except to do the `break`.

The result is as follows:

- The inner `j`-loop at first breaks immediately when j==0, because the value of `i` is **0**.
- The inner `j`-loop restarts because of the outer `i`-loop, now it breaks when j==1, because now the value of `i` is **1**.
- It restarts again and now it breaks when j==2.
- Etc.
- Etc.
- Until finally the `i`-loop ends, because it has reached the `batchsize` value.

This is really weird and looks like a mistake. I suspect you do not need the `i`-loop at all, so I suggest you **remove** it, and instead do something like **`if (j == batchsize) { break; }`** inside the `j`-loop.

Comment: Peter B, This was i suggestion from this forum
I tried it and forgott that i changed the code before i edit my post

Comment: Peter B, how would you recommend the loops so that will do as needed, thanks

Comment: I got that step to work now. but after i have runned batchsize it breaks and running the steps below, but after that i goes to the top, the sql question but i need it to run the next batchsize until it have done all the rows in datatable, any idea on how i can do that

Comment: It's best to create a new question if after making changes a different/new problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

If we prefer for loops instead of while loops, we can better understand how many loops we are in, so I rewrote your code with a for loop and if i == x is true, I ended the whole loop with break.

```cs
    int batchSize = 2;
    bool willBreak = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            DataRow dtRow = dt1.Rows[j];
            
            if (i == j) {
                break; // in there what you want as I understand
                willBreak=true;
            } 
            
            var number = dtRow.ItemArray[0];
            var surname = dtRow.ItemArray[1];
            var forename = dtRow.ItemArray[2];
            var emailAddress = dtRow.ItemArray[3];
            string taxidentifier = (string)dtRow.ItemArray[4];
            //string taxidentifier = "2211221143";

            if (Personnummer.Valid(taxidentifier))
            {

                body += "{\"itemId\": \"" + number + "\",\"subjectId\": \"" + taxidentifier + "\"},";

            }

            body = body.Remove(body.Length - 1);
            body += "]}";
        }
        if (willBreak) break;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: If i break like the code you shared, will i get back to get the next 2?
Getting error on willBreak = True;
Unreachable code detected